# Permission to Read a File

Tags: java, unix, file-permissions

I have a class which is storing meta data of file, that class have a string variable "filePermission".
filepermission variable have value like '777','770' etc.
now on the basis of file permission i want to put a check whether user can read file or not.
how i can achieve this by code.

Comment: Please show your existing attempt(s).

Answer (score 0):

User has READ permission when the leftmost digit is one of these values '4'/'5'/'7'. Extract that digit and put switch block.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String perm = "777";

    char[] result = perm.toCharArray();

    switch(result[0]){
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '7': System.out.println("User has read permission");
                break;
        default: 
            System.out.println("User DOESN'T have read permission");
            break;
    }       
}
```